# MemoryCache seems not to dispose all monitors

Tags: c#, synchronization, memorycache, domainunload

I've been working with System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache and I'm having some trouble regarding Monitors dispose. 
So a little bit of context, I'm trying to implement a cache where items get invalidated from changes on a file by using a custom `ChangeMonitor` (no I don't wan't to use `HostFileChangeMonitor`), based on a PubSub architecture.

I have 2 types of inserts on MemoryCache:

- One time insert, that is supposed to be removed on monitor changes or expirations:

  ```
      var monitor = new PubSubMonitor(cacheKey, subscription);
      policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(monitor);
      policy.SlidingExpiration = slidingSpan;
      policy.AbsoluteExpiration = expirationDate;
      policy.Priority = System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable;
      policy.RemovedCallback = (args) => {
          if (subscription != null) {
              subscription.Dispose();
              subscription = null;
          }
      };
  ```
- Long live insert, that is supposed to get re-added on monitor changes or by expiration:

  ```
      var monitor = new PubSubMonitor(cacheKey, subscription);
      policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(monitor);
      policy.SlidingExpiration = ObjectCache.NoSlidingExpiration;
      policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
      policy.Priority = System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable;
      policy.UpdateCallback = EncapsulateListener(cacheKey, invalidationCallback, subscription);
  ```

Here is the implementation of `EncapsulateListenerCallback`:

```
private CacheEntryUpdateCallback EncapsulateListenerCallback(string originalKey, CacheItemInvalidationCallback invalidationCallback, ISubscription subscription) {
        return (args) => {
            if (args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.ChangeMonitorChanged || args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired) {
                args.UpdatedCacheItem = new CacheItem(originalKey, invalidationCallback());

                var newPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                { //configurations
                    var newMonitor = new PubSubMonitor(originalKey, subscription);

                    newPolicy.ChangeMonitors.Add(newMonitor);
                    newPolicy.SlidingExpiration = ObjectCache.NoSlidingExpiration;
                    newPolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
                    newPolicy.Priority = System.Runtime.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable;
                    newPolicy.UpdateCallback = EncapsulateListenerCallback(originalKey, invalidationCallback, subscription);
                }
                args.UpdatedCacheItemPolicy = newPolicy;
            } else {
                if (subscription != null) {
                    subscription.Dispose();
                    subscription = null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And also `PubSubMonitor`:

```
public class PubSubMonitor : ChangeMonitor {
    private readonly string topic;
    private readonly ISubscription subscription;
    private volatile bool monitorDisposed = false;
    public PubSubMonitor(string topic, ISubscription subscription) : base() {
        bool initialized = false;
        try {
            this.topic = topic;
            this.subscription = subscription;
            this.subscription.OnMessage += this.InnerOnChange;
            initialized = true;
        } finally {
            InitializationComplete();
            if (!initialized) {
                Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private void InnerOnChange(object state) {
        lock (this) {
            if (!monitorDisposed) {
                this.subscription.OnMessage -= this.InnerOnChange;
                try {
                    base.OnChanged(state);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //log the error
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override string UniqueId => topic + "[" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "]";

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        lock (this) {
            this.subscription.OnMessage -= this.InnerOnChange;
            monitorDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`ISubscription` objects will invoke callbacks registered on `OnMessage` event to notify for a change.

My problem with this implementation is that sometimes, when my application is unloading a `System.NullReferenceException` is thrown by `MemoryCache` with this stack:

```
   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore.RemoveFromCache(System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheEntry, System.Runtime.Caching.CacheEntryRemovedReason, Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore.Remove(System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheKey, System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheEntry, System.Runtime.Caching.CacheEntryRemovedReason)
   at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheEntry.OnDependencyChanged(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor.OnChangedHelper(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.Caching.ChangeMonitor.OnChanged(System.Object)
   at MyNamespace.PubSubMonitor.InnerOnChange(System.Object)
   at MyNamespace.FileBasedPubSubSubscription.RaiseOnMessage(MyNamespace.PubSubMessage)
   at MyNamespace.FileBasedPubSubSubscription.OnFileEvent(System.String, System.Object, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at MyNamespace.FileBasedPubSubSubscription+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<SubscribeTopic>b__0(System.Object, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnChanged(System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

From what I was able to troubleshoot with DotPeek is that my subscription is raising an OnMessage even when the MemoryCache object is already Disposed. That subscription stops raising events when it is disposed (by disposing and disable raising events on `FileSystemWatcher`), and I do the dispose on update and remove callbacks.

Those `lock`'s on `PubSub` monitors were added to guarantee that dispose method is not invoked while we're on the `base.OnChange()`.

All items gets removed from cache and their monitors are disposed (from documentation and source code I was able to analyse), but somehow there are Monitors not getting disposed, or some cache item `UpdateCallback`/`RemoveCallback` not getting invoked, because file change events are still being raised.

Thanks all